# Update Android TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an simple android app that I want to write on the display the value of a single field, that belongs to a different class.

Using the simple text view I can write the initial value of the field but I don't know how to update the text on the display whenever the field has changed value.

Btw, it is my first android app so im still lost

Here is my activity code:

```
public class findIT extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PositionHolder ph = new PositionHolder();
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    //this.updateText();
    tv.setText("You are at "  + ph.getPosition());
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code in your other class where you are trying to update the TextView.

Comment: This is really impossible to answer without knowing what the PositionHolder class does and what is changing the value returned by getPosition. You need to notify the findIT Activity from the PositionHolder class when the position changes.

Comment: I believe Chris is just trying to do a Hello World. I doubt there are other activities other than findIT. PositionHolder is probably just a small helper class.

Comment: in fact PositionHolder is a listener class that grabs the position of the phone from a server! it also has instances of other classes. It works with the standard System.out.println but i just want to use th app from my phone so i can walk around and get updates on my position !!! i hope it makes sense ...

Comment: by the way , it is not gps psotion tracking , but bluetooth for indoor tracking...

Comment: Sounds neat. Just a tip, you should print to [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) instead of system.out and that way you can see the Log messages in [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) easily inside eclipse or from adb

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a TextView in an xml layout as following:

```
<TextView 
android:id="@id/textView01"
android:text="Enter your initial text "
android:layout_width="wrap content"
android:layout_height="wrap content"
></TextView>
```

Then write the following in your class after setContentView() function:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView01);
textView.setText("Enter whatever you Like!");
```

Answer (score 4):

Chris.... Here is a most basic way to develop an app. Divide up the problem into three pieces. The presentation or view. The algorithm or model. The Controller that responds to user and system events. This creates a "separation of concerns" such that the Controller owns the view and the model. You create the view using xml as in main.xml. You create a separate class to do the work say MyModel.java and of course there is the Controller or the Activity class say MyActivity.java. So the data comes from the model goes to the Controller that updates the view.

So your question is how to get the data from the model and update the view. Naturally this will take place in the controller, your Activity. The simplest way to do this is to put a button in the activity and when the user hits the button, call model.getLatestData() and update the view. This is PULLing data. The next way is for the Controller to check for an update say every minute. This is POLLING for data. The next way is for the Controller to register an interest in changes to the model and sit around waiting for the model to signal a change and then update the view. This is asynchronous PUSHING of data from the model to the controller and could be done with the OBSERVER pattern.

I know this makes no sense to you when you are struggling with trying to just get the code to work, but hopefully I have planted the seed of an idea in your head that will bother you and make sense sometime in the future.

JAL

Comment: do you read any blogs where you have gotten your opinions? Or are these just from years of personal experience. Just asking because I like this post.

Comment: @eternalmatt I am glad that you like my ramblings! I just like to abstract how I code and I have been coding since forever (Z80 assembly). mCv is from my Twisted OOP in C# tutorial. POLLING/PULLING/PUSHING was the entire subject of a book that I read. OBSERVER obviously is from the gang of four.

Comment: well actually is a kind of MVC i have, but my problem was that i try to do a simple app on android and i cannot update the text of the text view. Logger messages prove that the state of the variable i want to show has changed, but calling setView doesn't refresh the output of the screen. Thanks for your reply though, the seed was planted, but you just added a bit more water !

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to define a layout in xml, then when you create the TextView, you associate it with its layoutID. Something like:

> ```
> TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.something);
> ```

I can explain a little more, if you need, but this will give you a starting place to look for more answers.